# Gitlab upgrade fail 12.1.17 to 12.10.14

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

I was upgrading gitlab docker image. It's since 11.11.8 to the 14.Y.Z, also follow the document version.(https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/index.html#upgrade-paths)

But when I upgrade 12.10.14 (12.1.17 to 12.10.14), it's fail.

It's fail log.

```
bash[migrate gitlab-rails database] (gitlab::database_migrations line 54) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20220125-27-131h8bw" ----
STDOUT: rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, null, HTTP Error Rate, sum(rate(nginx_server_requests{code=~"5.*", host="*", %{environm..., HTTP Errors (%), %, 5xx Errors (%), -4, 2022-01-25 14:37:27.610755+00, 2022-01-25 14:37:27.610755+00, t, response_metrics_nginx_http_error_percentage).
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database_importers/common_metrics/importer.rb:20:in `block in execute'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database_importers/common_metrics/importer.rb:58:in `process_metric_details'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database_importers/common_metrics/importer.rb:48:in `block in process_panel'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database_importers/common_metrics/importer.rb:47:in `map'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database_importers/common_metrics/importer.rb:47:in `process_panel'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database_importers/common_metrics/importer.rb:38:in `block in process_group'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database_importers/common_metrics/importer.rb:37:in `map'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database_importers/common_metrics/importer.rb:37:in `process_group'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database_importers/common_metrics/importer.rb:28:in `block in process_content'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database_importers/common_metrics/importer.rb:27:in `map'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database_importers/common_metrics/importer.rb:27:in `process_content'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database_importers/common_metrics/importer.rb:18:in `execute'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/migrate/20190709220014_import_common_metrics_y_axis.rb:7:in `up'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:49:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

I didn't know how to fixed it.

Help me plz

Comment: Finally, I find the solution to this.
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/5299

The reason is PostgreSQL version
Gitlab 12.9 still using the PG version 10.12.
and unitl
Gitlab 12.10 need to PG version 11.*

that's the reason for this.
https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/database.html

There also give me the anss.

Comment: Additional, also [wait for all background migrations to finish](https://docs.gitlab.com/12.10/ee/update/index.html#checking-for-background-migrations-before-upgrading) after each upgrade step.